# Set Iframe "src" attribute dynamically using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I would like to set src attribute of Iframe in MVC view. I have tried following code but it didn't add src attribute to iframe.

```html
@section Style{
   
} @*end @section Style*@

@{
    Html.RenderAction("HeaderPartial", "Home", new { area = "Common" });
}

<iframe id="iframeProjectView" height="820" width="1665" scrolling="no" style="display: block"></iframe>

@section Script{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/EventsAssets.js")"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url = "@ViewData["url"]"; 
        var iframe = $("#iframeProjectView");
        iframe.attr('src', url);
    </script>

    @Html.DevExpress().GetScripts(
          new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
          new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView },
          new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors }
    )
}
```

When I redirect to this view, page doesn't display iframe. I have also checked view source and it doesn't add src attribute to iframe.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you rendering the `Script` section anywhere? `@RenderSection("Script")`. Also, view source won't reflect dynamic changes. Instead, look at the Elements (or similar) tab in your developer tools (hit F12) and search the DOM there.

Comment: Check for error's in console. Next add a `console.log(iframe)`, do you see your dom element? If not try wrapping your code in a document ready block, more than likely the code is executing before the item is there.

Comment: Try wrapping the src changing script code with $(document).ready(function(){  ...  } to ensure it is executed after the iframe has been initialized.

Comment: Make sense. I have put the code inside $(document).ready(function(){ ... } .It works now.  Thanks ALL.